# Microsoft dynamics crm learning using azure virtual machines

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to learn basics of dynamics crm 2011 and 2013.

I have MS azure subscription where I do have access to Dynamics CRM virtual machines. These virtual machines have the following flavors for Dynamics CRM

**GP 2013 Developer**

**GP 2013 R12**

**NAV 2015**

**GP 2015**

Which one of the above 4 virtual machine setup should I use just to learn very basics of Dynamics CRM? Specially the jquery part and some customization.

I am very new at CRM but have lot of back ground in asp.net mvc c# programming.

Comment: that 4 VM are not Dynamics CRM

Comment: what are they? I really need help

Comment: they are other Dynamics products, search on microsoft download server and you will find the trials for dynamics crm server

Comment: where can I find MS download server?

Comment: If you have a CRM licence you can provision a Server and manually install Dynamics CRM.

Comment: Is there any way I can practice CRM on Azure virtual machine?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27822

Comment: Thanks for download server information. Is there any way, I can install this on Azure virtual machine?

Comment: My job does not let me install any thing on my local machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use one of the SQL Server images and deploy everything on a single server if you want to test it out. Technically, it is not supported, but for evaluation purposes, this is the cheapest and easiest way.

Here's a tutorial that walks you through the steps for CRM 2013:
http://www.slideshare.net/jukkan/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-development-server-installation

Comment: If I want to demo CRM 2013 and Sharepoint 2013 integration, would I configure a seperate server for this to install Sharepoint on?  I haven't ever installed Sharepoint much less did CRM integration with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use trial CRM Online. You can register instance for you using following link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-free-trial-overview.aspx

Comment: I tried it.. I did not get a download or setup link. The page said that MS will get back to me. :(

Comment: That means that you did something wrong because I usually use Online for prototyping/demos e.t.c. I created and used more then 25 instances.

Comment: After I fill out my information, I get the following message: We've successfully received your request for a Concierge Trial!
If you've submitted your request during business hours we'll be in touch within 30 minutes. If you've missed us, don't worry, we'll be in touch as soon as we return the next business day!

Our standard business hours are between 9am and 5pm, Monday through Friday.

Comment: When was the last time you successfully created instances for crm?

Comment: I haven't got any kind of similar messages. Recheck following article that describes step-by-step creation of CRM Online Instance - [http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2013/06/20/quick-guide-to-creating-a-trial-on-crm-online.aspx](http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2013/06/20/quick-guide-to-creating-a-trial-on-crm-online.aspx)